# Playing Background sound in Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to play a background sound which runs throughout the application. Here I have 3 activities and the sound is started when the MAIN activity launches. 
I want to achieve these: 
1) play the bg sound continuously throughout the app whatever activity loads.
2) Switch off the sound when user clicks sound off button.
3) Stop the sound when the app closes.

So far I have tried this code to start the sound but it keeps on playing even if the app is closed.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    audioPlayer();
}

    boolean isPlayingSound = true;
public void onClickSound(View view) {
    final Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

    if(isPlayingSound){ 
        btn1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sound00);
        isPlayingSound=false;
        audioPlayer(false);/*Sound doesn't stops here*/
    } 
    else{ 
        btn1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sound11);
        isPlayingSound=true;
        audioPlayer(true);
    }     
}

public void audioPlayer(boolean status){  

    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bg);
    if(status) {
        mp.start();
    }
    else {
        mp.stop();
    }
}
```

Can anyone plz have a look and help me out here. Thanks for help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can playback the audio move to Service. you can reference ASOP music code
or look

[Binding to a Started Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Binding)

As discussed in the Services document, you can create a service that is both started and bound. That is, the service can be started by calling startService(), which allows the service to run indefinitely, and also allow a client to bind to the service by calling bindService().

If you do allow your service to be started and bound, then when the service has been started, the system does not destroy the service when all clients unbind. Instead, you must explicitly stop the service, by calling stopSelf() or stopService().

Comment: Thanks. Detailed info I got from http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html